# How to get Search Form on click of search icon

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

**This is my code**

**search icon for click**

```
<span id="et_search_icon"></span>
```

**search form**

> want to show this search from on click of search icon and

```
 <form role="search" method="get" class="et-search-form" action="run.php">
 <input type="search" class="et-search-field" />
</form>
<span class="et_close_search_field"></span>
```

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to find the problem? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery

```
$('#et_search_icon').click(function(){
  $('.et-search-form').show();
});
```

javascript

```
var form = document.getElementsByClassName('et-search-form');
function clickBtn () {
    form[0].style.display = 'block';
}
<span onClick="clickBtn()" id="et_search_icon"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Jquery:

```
$("#et-search-form").hide();
$("#et_search_icon").click(function(){
    $("#et-search-form").show();
})
```

HTML:
    Click here

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="et-search-form" action="run.php">
<input type="search" class="et-search-field" />
</form>
```